# Python: rank all values in a dataframe based on their similarity to an external value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with company names and employee numbers in the following form:

| Companyname | employee_num |
| --- | --- |
| Company A | 1478 |
| Company B | 12 |
| Company C | 490 |
| Company D | 34012 |

Now a user can input a number (e.g. 10) and the companies should be assigned a rank, based on how close their own employee number is compared to the input. Since I´m not a native english speaker I´m not quite sure if "similarity" is the correct term. Since only numbers will be compared, maybe "difference" would be better?

Anyway, the expected result for a input of 10 would be:

| Companyname | employee_num | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | 1478 | 3 |
| Company B | 12 | 1 |
| Company C | 490 | 2 |
| Company D | 34012 | 4 |

So since Company B (12 employees) is closest to the input of 10 it is assigned rank 1, Company D which is least similar is assigned rank 4.

If two companies have the same number of employees, they should be assigned the same rank.

I looked into the df.rank() function but it is unclear to me how I could rank based on a comparison value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) the companies this way :

```
N = 10 # <-- User's input simulation

df["rank"] = df["employee_num"].sub(N).abs().rank(method="dense")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  Companyname  employee_num  rank
0   Company A          1478  3.00
1   Company B            12  1.00
2   Company C           490  2.00
3   Company D         34012  4.00
4   Company E          1478  3.00 # <-- the Company E was added by me
```

Comment: **NB**: If the `Company D` should be *ranked* 5th in my example, use `.rank(method="min")`.